# Opencv: How to I get and then change values of "Mat vector"

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to do an operation like this however I cannot get the values of the vector Mat and change them. table is a 1 dimensional array by the way. Thanks.

```
vector<Mat> orjchannel; 
vector<Mat> refchannel; 

// There are some functions here 

for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 512; j++){
        double value = refchannel[i][j]; // This part does not work 
        orjchannel[i][j] = tables[value];
```

Comment: operator[] takes 1 integer. Did you mean `[i][j]`?

Comment: Yes since I dont konw how to reach that value I wrote somthing like what I mean

Comment: I edited it that way it does not work as well

Comment: Does Mat have operator[]?

Comment: What type is `tables`? You're trying to access a 1D vector `refchannel` with  double indices.

Answer (score 8):

With OpenCV, you typically access the values of a Mat with the `at<DATATYPE>(r,c)` command.  For example...

```
// Mat constructor
Mat data(4, 1, CV_64FC1);

// Set Value
data.at<double>(0,0) = 4;

// Get Value
double value = data.at<double>(0,0);
```

Comment: To further increase on this answer; You would need to use; refchannel.at(i).at<double>(j,k). The first 'at' selects one of the Mat objects in the vector, the second gives you the specified value in the mat (of the specified type).